# Using splash screen as a loader

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to use my a custom splash screen whenever my app comes back from background and i want the splash to be displayed until all data from the app is loaded. so actually the splash will be working as a loader.
Currently I have implemented DefaultLifecyleObserver to my Main class and on its onStart() method I start a new activity which i am using as a splash. In splash activity onCreate method i am doing nothing but calling finish() method after 3 seconds.
so basically whenever app returns from background it redirects to splash screen and after showing that for 3 seconds it shows me where i left.
Problem with it is that when app loads from background it shows where i left for 1 second and then it redirects to splash instead of instantly redirecting me to splash.
i have tried using onRestart onResume methods it doesnt work with my requirements too.

Comment: Did you try or consider using the 'onPause()' event method to "finish current work" and maybe prepare the splash sceen for when the app resumes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Eskapone can you please elaborate